AWS Lambda Giving Error for Python Version 3.10.11
I created lambda_function.py file in windows 10. I am using python version: 3.10.11 in Windows.
When I run script it working in Windows 10, but when running AWS Lambda, I am getting error at line: import pandas as pd
Windows 10 Logs
(io_script) E:\env\abc\io_script\Scripts>python --version
Python 3.10.11

AWS Lambda Logs: AWS Lambda python version is 3.10
[ERROR] AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/var/task/pandas/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    _delvewheel_patch_1_5_4()
  File "/var/task/pandas/__init__.py", line 9, in _delvewheel_patch_1_5_4
    os.add_dll_directory(libs_dir)INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 433.15 ms  Phase: init Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.Unknown
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 3141.57 ms   Phase: invoke   Status: timeout
START RequestId: f19a6b90-0b68-4824-b13c-2f64a1c98969 Version: $LATEST
2024-07-02T16:53:26.432Z f19a6b90-0b68-4824-b13c-2f64a1c98969 Task timed out after 3.20 seconds

lambda_function.py
import requests
import json
import math
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize #New
import datetime
from datetime import date
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('hi')


AWS Lambda runs on Amazon Linux (which is derived from RedHat).  You will not be able to use Windows-specific functionality in the Lambda runtime. add_dll_directory is only available on Windows and not present on python distributions for Linux.
It looks like the error is coming from within pandas. So it would seem you have managed to install a version of pandas that is for windows. Did you install and package your Lambda zip file on Windows?
Use something like WSL to develop and test your code outside of the Lambda runtime. When running under WSL, pip will download and install versions of pandas appropriate for Linux rather than Windows.
Alternatively, use pip download to find wheels appropriate for the Lamdba runtime. eg.
pip download --platform manylinux_2_17_x86_64 pandas 

